# Mockito Test - SimpMessageHeaderAccessor cannot be returned by getHeaders() getHeaders() should return MessageHeaders

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

How to write the unit test, because it including the internal call other method.

```
public class MyService implements UserDestinationResolver {

    @Override
    public UserDestinationResult myMethod(Message<?> message){
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class);

****some logics to use access to get the return value UserDestinationResult***

    return UserDestinationResult;
```

getAccessor here is a static method from MessageHeaderAccessor class

```
@Nullable
public static <T extends MessageHeaderAccessor> T getAccessor(Message<?> message, Class<T> requiredType) {
        return getAccessor(message.getHeaders(), requiredType);
    }
```

here is my test case:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Message<?> message;

    private SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor;

    @Mock
    private UserDestinationResult userDestinationResult;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void set_up(){
        accessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    }

    @Test
    public void resolveDestination(){
    when(MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message,
                SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class)).thenReturn(accessor);

    """""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    assertEquals(excepted, actual);
}
```

an Error occurs:

> SimpMessageHeaderAccessor cannot be returned by getHeaders()
>   getHeaders() should return MessageHeaders
>   If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on. Due to the
>   nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>   1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.    Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency
>   testing.
>   2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
>      - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.

Message is a interface, I mock it as a instance, but it cannot get the headers at all, it is a mock...how can I solve this problem..

Comment: What is returned by `SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class)`? Is that some mock? Are you trying to stub a POJO?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock a static method with vanilla mockito.

I would suggest creating a protected method in MyService which would wrap the static call, and then mock it:

```
public class MyService implements UserDestinationResolver {

    @Override
    public UserDestinationResult myMethod(Message<?> message){
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor = getAccessor(message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class);
     ...
    }

    protected SimpMessageHeaderAccessor getAccessor(Message<?> message, Class<T> requiredType){
         return SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class);
    }
```

Then in test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Message<?> message;


    @Mock
    private UserDestinationResult userDestinationResult;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private MyService myService;

    @Before
    public void set_up(){
        accessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    }

    @Test
    public void resolveDestination(){
       // Arrange
       doREturn(accessor).when(myService).getAccessor(message,
                SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class));

      ....
}
```

The change here is that you need to Spy on MyService to be able to mock the protected method.

Comment: Macjej, I made a mistake, and I just change the code SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class); shoule be SimpMessageHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.class);

Comment: Ok, did you try it out after that?